# Blocks, statements, class declaration in java

Tags: java

I cannot find an answer online so i need help, i was wondering if 
`Class class{ *insert code here*}` 
is considered a statement and also at the start of the curly braces to the last, is that considered a block?.

Comment: no, it's considered a class (well, if you replace Class by class, and class by something that is allowed as class name)

Comment: it's considered a class.

Comment: thanks so much for replying, what about inbetween the braces? would that be called a block? because i know control structures ARE considered as statements and blocks

Comment: Your keyword class is vital part

Comment: yes im sorry i realize class needed to be a name of a class and not the keyword and "Class" needed to be "class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since java is a case-sensitive so there is no any `Class` keyword
`class MyTestClass{}` would be java class, not statement.

you could say `System.out.println(0);` is statement and `if(something==somethings){}` is the if block but these both must be inside `java class`

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the best response

Comment: @TheSilence17 my pleasure vote me up.

Comment: i only have a 11 rep, i need 15 to vote up. And what about the main method? can those curly braces be considered a block and a statement?

Comment: Still you dont understand difference between block and statement ?

Comment: i do understand the difference before the curly braces, the actual line of code for the main method... what is that called? a statement? a method invocation? both?

Answer (score 1):

first curly braces are always contain body of class. if you want to declare blocks inside class then again create curly braces in your class.

Comment: so it is not considered a block if its for the class, but if i use another pair of curly braces inside it would be?

Comment: yes. another pair will be your block that will call at the time of object creation.

Comment: what about the main method? would that be considered a block?

Comment: boss. it's a method. if you are asking about main method why don't you ask about other method. method are function with method body inside braces.